# PoA network confusion resolving using geth

Tags: go-ethereum, poa, geth-clique, pow

I am planning to move from PoW to PoA consensus (clique) using geth. But I am confused of some of the topics -

- 1) Empty blocks are created periodically? What is the size of an
  empty block?
- 2) Is it possible to avoid empty block creation? That is new block
  will be only created whenever there is a new transaction ?
- 3) I have observed that with unlocking the coinbase account new block
  is not created? Is it ok? if not what can be logic behind this?
- 4) What is the process of adding new sealer in PoA network?
- 5) What can be the reasonable period for new block?
- 6) what can be the possible issues behind period=0

I would highly appreciate if someone provides some explanations. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

1) I'm curious about this one ! :)

2) Yes, if you set period to 0, commit new mining work whenever a transaction arrives

3) Unlocking is done "under-the-hood" it's not a transaction, it's more an "authentication"

4) Sealers are defined in the genesis file, but you can add it by using Geth

```
clique.propose("Sealer address", true)
```

5) It depends on your configuration if you set it to 1sec your tx will be processed very quickly, but after a while, you will run out of space, and if you put a very high amount it will take a long time to validate your transactions

6) On PoA if you set period = 0, each time you trigger a transaction, it will generate a new block

I hope that helps! :)

Comment: Yes. I have understood all of your answers. In the mean time, I have tried to find the answers in the internet which mostly  match with your answers.So  +1 for your answer. Still I will wait for other answers before I accept the answer. thanks for your reply. :)